# Column does not exist on creating a view with a function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make a function on postgres that receives an user email, gets the user id from a `users` table and creates a view based on that user id. This is the function:

```
create or replace function userpins_fn(email_tk text)
returns int
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
as 
$$
declare
userid_tk integer;
begin
userid_tk = (select id from users where email = email_tk);

create or replace view userpins_view as select
level_pg, latitude_pg, longitude_pg, data_pg, hora_pg
from saved_pins
where userid_pg = userid_tk;

return  userid_tk;
end
$$
```

It returns the user id just because it has to return something, it's not really relevant.
So everything is fine here, it executes perfectly, but when I do `select userpins_fn('useremail@mail.com');` to update the view so it matches that user email, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column "id_user" does not exist
LINE 4: where utilizadorid_pg = id_user
                                ^
QUERY:  create or replace view pinsgajoview as select
nivel_pg, latitude_pg, longitude_pg, data_pg, hora_pg
from pins_guardados
where utilizadorid_pg = id_user
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function userpins_fn(text) line 7 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42703
```

I don't get it... I've done similar functions and had no error like this... Is my postgres bugged? Am I missing something so basic that I can't even notice? Please help me...

Comment: what is `id_user`? it is not declared in your function, just in the `return id_user` ;)

Comment: i was editing it to post here, forgot to change that too xD it's edited now

Comment: you can't do that. If you want to "pass a parameter to a view", the solution is to create a set returning function instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to cannot be done the way you try to do it

See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST) :

> Variable substitution currently works only in SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE,
> and DELETE commands, because the main SQL engine allows query
> parameters only in these commands. To use a non-constant name or value
> in other statement types (generically called utility statements), you
> must construct the utility statement as a string and EXECUTE it.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me, thank you!